# How to add multiple exceptions to a rule so that web crawlers do crawl those pages?

Tags: json, robots.txt

I have the following code that works with the following exception to the /policies/ page but I need it to also allow for additional exceptions that I want to explicitly list.

```
# this code works
{%- comment -%}


{% for group in robots.default_groups %}
  {{- group.user_agent }}

  {%- for rule in group.rules -%}
    {%- unless rule.directive == 'Disallow' and rule.value == '/policies/'  -%}
      {{ rule }}
    {%- endunless -%}

  {%- endfor -%}

  {%- if group.sitemap != blank -%}
      {{ group.sitemap }}
  {%- endif -%}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried adding additional rules like this, but the robot.txt file just grows longer with duplicate disallow entries

```
# this doesn't work
{%- comment -%}


{% for group in robots.default_groups %}
  {{- group.user_agent }}

  {%- for rule in group.rules -%}
    {%- unless rule.directive == 'Disallow' and rule.value == '/policies/'  -%}
      {{ rule }}
    {%- endunless -%}

  {%- endfor -%}

  {%- for rule in group.rules -%}
    {%- unless rule.directive == 'Disallow' and rule.value == '/blogs/'  -%}
      {{ rule }}
    {%- endunless -%}

  {%- endfor -%}

  {%- if group.sitemap != blank -%}
      {{ group.sitemap }}
  {%- endif -%}
{% endfor %}
```